# Display Text Over Full Screen YouTube iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

How would you display text over a full screen YouTube iframe? Setting the [z-index to the maximum no longer works](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=882225) in the new stable Chrome and other popular browsers.

[jsfiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://jsfiddle.net/50vq8rw7/1/)

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="overlay">Test</div>

#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:12%;
    opacity:1;
    /*background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); or just this*/
    z-index: 2147483647;
    color:#fff;
    bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    font-size:300%;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance; I'm learning CSS/HTML and I can't figure this out!

Comment: You mean to say you have to display the text over the video. right? or can you share the expect output?

Comment: @NarendraVerma Yes display the text over video, while the video is in full screen.